# PHPMYADMIN Permission Denied on Import from CSV

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I'm on CPANEL and I need to import some CSV files into the correspondant DB table.
I'm using the phpmyadmin import interface but this is what happens:

```
QUERY SQL:
LOAD DATA INFILE  '/path' INTO TABLE  `table` FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ';' ENCLOSED BY  '"' ESCAPED BY  '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY  '\r\n'
MYSQL MESSAGE:
#1045 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Have you checked that the user you are logged in with has permissions to access the database you are trying to import the data to?

Comment: Can you query the database at all? Loading data requires write privileges

Comment: No problems in querying the db.
I've granted all privileges to all existing users.
(And I've also added all these users to the db)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the user doesn't have access to the database.

Before a user can access your database, you must add the user to the database.

To add a user to a database, follow these steps:

1. In the Databases section of the cPanel home screen, click MySQL® Databases.
2. Under Add User to Database, select the user that you want to add in the User list box.
3. In the Database list box, select the database.
4. Click Add.
5. Click the check boxes to grant the user specific privileges, or click the ALL PRIVILEGES check box to grant the user all permissions to the database.
6. Click Make Changes.

More info: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/cpanel/cpanel-database-features/managing-mysql-databases#Adding-a-user-to-a-database

Comment: Thank you Dan but I've inserted all the existing users (and I've also granted all possible permissions) but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue.  cPanel requires granting file privileges in order to do this.  If you are using GoDaddy Shared Hosting, this is not doable.  You need to switch to a VPS or dedicated server.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same situation, it seems that the user in the query was using the cpanel user instead of the database user created in cpanel database section.

What I did I create same user in mysql with cpanel and use same password.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).